# Can't import a function to my component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

```
const getWidthFactory = isMobileFromSSR => () => {
 const isSSR = typeof window === "undefined";
 const ssrValue = isMobileFromSSR
  ? Responsive.onlyMobile.maxWidth
  : Responsive.onlyTablet.minWidth;

 return isSSR ? ssrValue : window.innerWidth;
};

const ProfilePage = ({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, isMobileFromSSR }) => (
 <>
  <Layout GenericHeadingComponent={HomepageHeading}
   isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
   logOutUser={logOutUser}
   getWidth={getWidthFactory(isMobileFromSSR)}
  >
   /* other stuff */
  </Layout>
 </>
)
```

This seems to work when the declared function is in the component file but not when I import it?

This is how i have the function set up in its own file to be exported:

`utils/utils.js`

```
import {
 Responsive,
} from 'semantic-ui-react'


export function getWidthFactory(isMobileFromSSR) {
 return function () {
  var isSSR = typeof window === "undefined";
  var ssrValue = isMobileFromSSR ? Responsive.onlyMobile.maxWidth : Responsive.onlyTablet.minWidth;
  return isSSR ? ssrValue : window.innerWidth;
 };
};
```

I think what is tripping me up is in the version where the function exists in the file, it seems to be leveraging the parameter `isMobileFromSSR`

So how would you rewrite this so it would work as exported function with the parameter?

**UPDATE**

I am importing it like this or tried to...

```
 import { getWidthFactory } from  '../../util/util'
```

Comment: How are you importing it

Comment: Make sure the path is correct (util vs utils).

Comment: @FelixKling That was it! Thanks my friend!

Comment: Why are you importing with { } as you are not exporting within {} ?

Comment: @MohanRamalingam: There are multiple ways to create *named* exports, `export {foo, bar}` is just one of them. You can create named export by directly exporting the declaration, such as `export const foo = 42;` or `export function someFunction(){}`, as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Always start component names with a **capital letter**. React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

In your case **getWidthFactory** should be like **GetWidthFactory**

Comment: It doesn't look like `getWidthFactory` is a component.